# This nested cursor loop is looping forever

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table that contains desired table names, column names, column data types, and column data length that I want to create a new database with.

right now I am working nesting some cursors to print out each unique table name and their accompanying column names.

when I run the below code it loops forever.  What am I missing?

```
    BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    DECLARE spC1 CURSOR

    FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT tblNm       
    FROM tblDef
    DECLARE @curTabNm AS varchar(60) = ''
    DECLARE @curColNm as varchar(60) = ''
    DECLARE @Outer_Loop AS int = 0
    OPEN spC1


    FETCH NEXT FROM spC1 INTO @curTabNm
    WHILE @Outer_Loop = 0
    PRINT @curTabNm
    BEGIN
        DECLARE spC2 CURSOR 
        FOR
        SELECT colNm FROM tblDef
        WHERE tblNm = @curTabNm

        open spC2
        FETCH NEXT FROM spC2 INTO @curColNm
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT @curColNm
            FETCH NEXT FROM spC2 INTO @curColNm
        END
        CLOSE spC2

        DEALLOCATE spC2
        FETCH NEXT FROM spC1 INTO @curTabNm
        SET @Outer_Loop = 1
    END
    CLOSE spC1
    DEALLOCATE spC1
END
```

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but technically I think the outer loop while is repeating the PRINT @curTabNm and not the BEGIN block.  Put the print within the BEGIN Block to be sure

Comment: Curious that the outer loop doesn't check `@@Fetch_Status`. Not that it matters since it isn't used inside the loop.

Comment: This is so slow because loops in sql are horribly inefficient. Nested cursors is guaranteed to be super slow. The way you make it faster is to throw away the cursor and use set based logic instead. This could easily be done in a single query. There is absolutely no need for looping here.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond yes, you're correct. So this will be looping infinitely there.

Comment: The point of this is to build a CREATE TABLE statement and execute it, not just simply print out found records.

Comment: Provide the ddl and sample data for your temp table along with the desired output and I will happily show you how to do this with no cursors. We can leverage a query to build dynamic sql. That isn't too tough.

Comment: Of course I would ask why you are storing the definition like this. If you want to use this to create a database why not store the proper ddl instead? That would be even simpler.

Comment: Hey thanks for the downvote!

Comment: 'tblNm colNm colTyp colLen colReq
account endDate String NULL 0
account beginningBalance String 12 0
account vSource String 255 0
assignment vSource String 255 0
assignment schoolNum String 7 1
assignment calendarName String 30 1
assignment courseNum String 13 1
assignment sectionNum Int 5 1
attendance periodSeq Int 3 0
attendance code String NULL 1
attendance comments String 50 0
attendanceExcuse schoolNum String 7 1
attendanceExcuse calendarName String 30 1
attendanceExcuse code String NULL 1
attendanceExcuse description String 50 1

Comment: I can't add editing. please look at the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step here is to create consumable ddl and sample data. I left off some of the datatypes that you said are not yet defined from your client.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #something
(
    tblNm sysname
    , colNm sysname
    , colTyp varchar(20)
    , colLen int
    , colReq bit
)

insert #something(tblNm, colNm, colTyp, colLen, colReq)
values
('account', 'studentNum', 'String', 15, 0)
,('account', 'employNum', 'String', 15, 0)
,('account', 'firstName', 'String', 35, 0)
,('account', 'lastName', 'String', 40, 0)
,('assignment', 'vSource', 'String', 255, 0)
,('assignment', 'schoolNum', 'String', 7, 1)
,('assignment', 'calendarName', 'String', 30, 1)
,('assignment', 'courseNum', 'String', 13, 1)
```

Now that we have data to work with we can work on the actual query here. This uses the FOR XML trick to generate a delimited list. In this case the delimited list is our columns. We then use some grouping in the outer query to get each table. The code looks like this.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'create table [' + tblNm + '](' + STUFF((select ', [' + s2.colNm + '] ' + Case s2.colTyp when 'String' then 'varchar' end 
            + isnull('(' + convert(varchar(4), s2.colLen) + ') ', ' ')
            + case s2.colReq when 1 then 'NOT ' else '' end + 'NULL'
        from #something s2
        where s2.tblNm = s.tblNm
        order by s2.colNm
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1, '') + ');'
from #something s
group by s.tblNm

select @SQL
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

That is it. The whole thing. When you are happy with the contents of the @SQL variable you can simply uncomment the execute statement and it will create your tables.

As stated previously the load on the system is not likely going to be huge for using cursors here but once you learn this type of technique it really is a lot simpler than cursors and it is far less code.

Comment: for the first step, after the insert values bit, do I have to manually key in those values? because the reference table they are pulled from is thousands of records long.

Comment: No of course not. That is so I had a table to work with. You would query directly against your existing table.

Comment: Also, this is generating null values in the 'select ', [' + s2.colNm + '] ' + CASE s2.colTyp when 'String' then 'varchar' end
   + isnull('(' + convert(varchar(4), s2.colLen) + ') ',' ')
   + case s2.colReq when 1 then 'NOT ' else '' end + 'NULL'
  FROM [CCS_CampusSchema]..[tblDef] s2' part

Comment: in a new answer I'll post the query, queried data, and output

Comment: If you are getting NULL that means that some of the columns are NULL. None of the sample data had NULL in them. You will have to handle NULL values with an ISNULL or COALESCE.

Comment: i dont think any of them are null; BTW THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP :)

Comment: At least one of the columns must be NULL. That is what would be returned when doing string concatenation with a NULL value.

Comment: Actually what is was is I had failed to edit your first case statement to accept ints.  but I purged the null containing records in the ddl, and edited your case statement. 

and it works like a charm! you are awesome Sean, THANK!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118449/discussion-between-mkasper-and-sean-lange).

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE spC1 CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT tblNm       
    FROM tblDef
    DECLARE @curTabNm AS varchar(60) = ''
    DECLARE @curColNm as varchar(60) = ''
    DECLARE @Outer_Loop AS int = 0
    OPEN spC1


    FETCH NEXT FROM spC1 INTO @curTabNm

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE spC2 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT colNm FROM tblDef
        WHERE tblNm = @curTabNm
        open spC2

        FETCH NEXT FROM spC2 INTO @curColNm

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT @curColNm
            FETCH NEXT FROM spC2 INTO @curColNm
        END

        CLOSE spC2
        DEALLOCATE spC2

        FETCH NEXT FROM spC1 INTO @curTabNm
    END
    CLOSE spC1
    DEALLOCATE spC1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah it was at lines

```
    WHILE @Outer_Loop = 0
PRINT @curTabNm
```

are in opposite order. whoops!

Comment: Please for the sake of your system get rid of this looping concept.

Comment: how else would you suggest? there's a lot of documentation on this

Comment: From what you have posted this is nothing more complicated than a simple select statement. Just because there is documentation on a feature does not mean it is a good approach.

Comment: But i don't want to simply print out found values, I want to build a CREATE TABLE statement, this is simply for debugging.

Comment: See my comment above. You don't need a cursor for this.

Comment: This type of cursor loop has a very minimal impact on the system and it very easy to understand compared to a set based approach.

Comment: @JoeC the impact may be minimal but a set based approach is so simple for this type of thing. And what a better way to start thinking set based than a simple exercise. Honestly I don't think a set based approach to this would be confusing. Certainly not as confusing as nested cursors.

Answer (score 0):

```
tblNm   colNm   colTyp  colLen  colReq
account personID    Decimal NULL    0
account studentNum  String  15  0
account employNum   String  15  0
account firstName   String  35  0
account lastName    String  40  0
account birthDate   String  NULL    0
account accountNumber   Decimal NULL    0
account accountPIN  String  50  0
account reminder    String  5   0
account remAmount   String  5   0
account blockConcessions    String  5   0
account blockAlaCarte   String  5   0
account singlePurch String  5   0
account eligibility String  20  0
account certifiedType   String  20  0
account startDate   String  NULL    0
account endDate String  NULL    0
account beginningBalance    String  12  0
account vSource String  255 0
assignment  vSource String  255 0
assignment  schoolNum   String  7   1
assignment  calendarName    String  30  1
assignment  courseNum   String  13  1
assignment  sectionNum  Int 5   1
assignment  groupName   String  50  1
assignment  assignmentName  String  50  1
assignment  abbreviation    String  5   1
assignment  assignmentSeq   String  5   0
assignment  totalPoints String  5   1
assignment  curveName   String  80  0
assignment  dueDate String  NULL    1
assignment  assignedDate    String  NULL    0
assignment  multiplier  String  6   0
assignment  description String  255 0
assignment  objectives  String  255 0
assignment  references  String  255 0
assignmentScore schoolNum   String  7   1
assignmentScore calendarName    String  30  1
assignmentScore courseNum   String  13  1
assignmentScore sectionNum  Int 5   1
assignmentScore groupName   String  50  1
assignmentScore assignmentName  String  50  1
assignmentScore studentNum  String  15  1
assignmentScore score   String  20  1
assignmentScore flag    String  20  0
assignmentScore comments    String  250 0
assignmentScore vSource String  255 0
attendance  vSource String  255 0
attendance  schoolNum   String  7   1
attendance  calendarName    String  30  1
attendance  studentNum  String  15  1
attendance  date    DateTime    NULL    1
attendance  scheduleSeq String  3   0
attendance  periodSeq   Int 3   0
attendance  code    String  NULL    1
attendance  comments    String  50  0
attendanceExcuse    schoolNum   String  7   1
attendanceExcuse    calendarName    String  30  1
attendanceExcuse    code    String  NULL    1
attendanceExcuse    description String  50  1
attendanceExcuse    status  String  20  1
attendanceExcuse    excuse  String  20  1
attendanceExcuse    vSource String  255 0
behaviorEvent   vSource String  255 0
behaviorEvent   eventType   String  100 1
behaviorEvent   incidentID  Int 0   1
behaviorEvent   eventID Int 50  1
behaviorEvent   referralEmployNum   String  15  0
behaviorEvent   adminEmployNum  String  15  0
behaviorEvent   weaponCode  String  2   0
behaviorEvent   calendarName    String  30  1
behaviorResolution  eventID String  50  1
behaviorResolution  studentNum  String  15  1
behaviorResolution  resolutionDate  DateTime    NULL    1
behaviorResolution  resolutionTime  String  20  1
behaviorResolution  endDate DateTime    NULL    0
behaviorResolution  ParentInvolvementComment    String  255 0
behaviorResolution  ParentCode  Int NULL    0
behaviorResolution  AssignedAlternateEducation  String  50  0
behaviorResolution  AdjudicationCode    String  50  0
behaviorResolution  ArrestCode  String  50  0
behaviorResolution  LLEOffice   String  50  0
behaviorResolution  LLENotified String  50  0
behaviorResolution  Duration    Int NULL    0
behaviorResolution  adminEmployNum  String  50  0
behaviorResolution  DisciplinaryActionComment   String  255 0
behaviorResolution  resolutionType  String  50  0
behaviorResolution  vSource String  255 0
behaviorRole    vSource String  255 0
behaviorRole    OffenderType    String  NULL    0
behaviorRole    injury  String  NULL    1
behaviorRole    relationshipToSchool    String  NULL    1
behaviorRole    InfractionComment   String  NULL    0
behaviorRole    ReceivedServices    Boolean NULL    0
behaviorRole    WeaponCount Int NULL    0
behaviorRole    WeaponDetectedMethod    String  NULL    0
behaviorRole    victimType  String  NULL    0
behaviorRole    eventID String  50  1
behaviorRole    studentNum  String  15  1
behaviorRole    role    String  15  1
behaviorRole    demerits    String  5   0
bus number  String  10  1
bus description String  250 0
bus contracted  String  5   0
bus vSource String  255 0
busRider    vSource String  255 0
busRider    schoolNum   String  7   1
busRider    calendarName    String  30  1
busRider    studentNum  String  15  1
busRider    inBusNumber String  10  0
busRider    inTime  String  20  0
busRider    inBusStop   String  20  0
busRider    outBusNumber    String  10  0
busRider    outTime String  20  0
busRider    outBusStop  String  20  0
busRider    lateBus String  10  0
busRider    transMiles  String  7   0
```

Comment: There seems to be quite a bit of logic in here. Why are all your dates listed as strings but the len is NULL? Should those really be datetime columns?

Comment: @SeanLange thats just coming from the legacy system we are migrating from.  the tsql has to translate these values and define the columns accordingly

Comment: Right I assumed that. So what about the string that have NULL for a length? Are those datetime columns or are they in fact varchar. If they are varchar what length should you use when the length in the table is NULL? And what about decimals?

Comment: The client has not informed me yet to this, can we ignore those records at the moment?